# Excel checking if row is part of a group

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro to create some order in a very large excel doc. After a few operations on a specific selection, I would like to check if there are rows in that selected range that are grouped, and if so, they need to be ungrouped. After ungrouping all the rows (could be some seperate groups in the range, could be one big group or not even grouped at all), they need to be grouped all together. The part of the code below starts with selecting the specific range, I think the solution is looping through the range and checking all the rows if they are part of a group, and if so, they would be needed to be ungrouped. But Don't know how to translate this concept into a working code :)
Also, an example of a range before the ungrouping/grouping operation is included below.

```
Range(Cells(Rstart, "H"), Cells(Rend, "H")).Select
Selection.Rows.Ungroup
Selection.Rows.Group
```

[image]

Comment: What isn't working with what you have tried? What you have written works for me (though you could use a With statement e.g. With Range("A1:A11").Rows: .Ungroup: .Group : End With

Comment: Have a look at the `Outline` level of the row.  E.g. `Sheet1.Rows(3).outlinelevel`

Comment: If there aren't any groups in the selected range, executing the macro generates a error message.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook so something like Selection.Rows.outlinelevel = 1 ?
Edit, just tried it, this solves my problem, you could post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you mean to do.
At any rate, I guess this will help you.

1. **Selecting complete rows**.

   ```
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Selection
   rng.EntireRow.Select
   ```
2. **Ungrouping** (e.g., [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/16748-check-if-rows-are-grouped-or-not)).
   Maybe you can use the `Outlinelevel` to determine whether a row is grouped.
   This will ungroup rows in the first 20.

   ```
   Sub x()
       Dim lngRow As Long
       For lngRow = 1 To 20
           If ActiveSheet.Rows(lngRow).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
               Do While ActiveSheet.Rows(lngRow).OutlineLevel > 1
                   ActiveSheet.Rows(lngRow).Ungroup
               Loop
           End If
       Next
   End Sub
   ```
3. **Grouping**.
   You already know how to do this.

Comment: Was struggling to check all the rows for being part of a group, didn't know about the 'outlinelevel', I just set all the rows to outlinelevel 1 at first and then just grouping them.