# How to distinguish Cells that are Filtered out from the ones that are just Grouped (Both hidden)

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code both, the filtered out and the grouped rows give true in the If condition:

```
'Cycle that identifies hidden and unhidden cells giving 0 to hidden ones and 1 to unhidden ones.
For i = 0 To dimensionsMatrix(1) - positionDataSequence(1) - 1
    If Sheets(STR_SHEET).Range("sequence_cell_reference_dataleft").Offset(i, 0).Rows.Hidden _
        Or dataMatrix(positionDataSequence(1) + i, positionDataSequence(2)) = 0 Then
        dataMatrix(positionDataSequence(1) + i, positionDataSequence(2)) = 0
    End If
Next
```

How to do so that ONLY the filtered rows and NOT the Grouped ones give true on the If condition above?

Thanks

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259454/excel-checking-if-row-is-part-of-a-group